# How can I properly iterate through list items of a <ul> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following `<ul>`:

```
<ul>
     <li class='test selected'></li>
     <li class='test'></li>
     <li class='test'></li>
     <li class='test'></li>
     <li>separator</li>
     <li class='test'></li>
     <li class='test'></li>
     <li class='test'></li>
</ul>
```

I am able to select the first element and iterate through the `<li>` prior to the separator via jquery like so:

```
li = $('.selected'); //currently selected <li>
if ($(li).next('.test').length) {
     $(li).removeClass('selected');
     $(li).next('.test').addClass('selected');
}
```

This is working fine up until I reach a separator (in other words, a `<li>` with no '.test' class). At the point of reaching the first separator, I need to know how to see my next '.test'.

If it helps any, the `li`'s are being generated dynamically. Also, I am firing this event on `keydown()`.

Any thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: `.next('.test')` will only return the next item when it matches the selector, it will not skip over ones that don't match.

Answer (score 4):

Change both your `.next('.test')` to `.nextAll('.test').first()`

next() only looks at the next sibling, whereas [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) searches all future siblings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) along with [$.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) like this:

```
li = $('.selected');
if ($(li).nextAll('.test').eq(0).length) {
    $(li).removeClass('selected');
    $(li).nextAll('.test').eq(0).addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: eq(0) is the same as .first(), and also :first yes?

Answer (score 1):

jquery is *transveral* this means it selectd (and applies) thingd to the full selection. Moreover it's *functional*, meaning you can chain methods (for nearly all of them).

in your case, this ***should*** do (but won't).

```
$('li.test.selected').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected');
```

Here lies something special. `.next()` is not the next in the jquery selection, but the next sibling element in the dom, whatever the list of element is! (I believe it's a jquery documentation bug). Hence, this will work only while "li" have the test class.

to solve that issue you can use this:

```
$('li.test.selected').removeClass('selected').nextAll('.test:first').addClass('selected');
```

and [here is your standard and mandatory fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrL2q/1/).